# I'm trying to send email through 'localhost' in Python but it keeps giving me an "Error 61"

Tags: python, email, localhost

I'm running a Mac OS X and used postfix to enable localhost.
This is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`netstat`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/netstat.1.html) to verify that a SMTP server is bound to port 25 of an appropriate interface in the first place.

Comment: I'm not trying to send it through port 25, but rather using  127.0.0.1 (localhost) as SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

Check the postfix log file, which might be at `/var/log/mail` or something similar, depending on how you installed postfix.